# Inno Setup doesnt restart at PrepareToInstall section

Tags: inno-setup, reboot, pascalscript

I am trying to prompt the user to restart the computer after enabling .NET 3.5, which is necessary for MSSQLServer. 
Example:

```pascal
function PrepareToInstall(var NeedsRestart: Boolean): String;
begin
  Log('PrepareToInstall() called');
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  if (Version.Major = 10) then begin
   NeedsRestart :=True;
  end
end;
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: What is your inno setup version?

Comment: I am on Version 5.6.1

Comment: What would also help is a detailed order in which the functions and procedures are called. I could not fully understand how to build an installer based on the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NeedsRestart` parameter is considered only if [`PrepareToInstall` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=PrepareToInstall) actually aborts an installation (by returning a non-empty string). What you probably do not want to do. In other words, you are abusing `PrepareToInstall` event function (and incorrectly anyway).

Use [`NeedRestart` event function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptevents&anchor=NeedRestart) instead:

```pascal
[Code]

function NeedRestart(): Boolean;
var
  Version: TWindowsVersion;
begin
  GetWindowsVersionEx(Version);
  Result := (Version.Major >= 10);
end;
```